# How to add new custom fields to existing createCustomerAddress graphql mutation

Tags: magento2, graphql

```
mutation {
  createCustomerAddress(input: {
    region: {
      region: "Arizona"
      region_code: "AZ"
    }
    country_code: US
    Custom_field1:
    Custom_field2  
}
```